# Regular expression and unicode literals

Tags: python, regex, unicode, unicode-literals

I'd like to remove some characters from a string (either byte string or unicode string) using a regular expression like this:

`pattern = re.compile(ur'\u00AE|\u2122', re.UNICODE)`

If the characters are specified as unicode literals the resulting regexp does not work properly on byte string.

```
q = 'Canon\xc2\xae  EOS  7D'
pattern.sub('', q)  # 'Canon\xc2  EOS  7D'
```

If I convert the argument of the substitution to a unicode string, however, it works as expected...

```
pattern.sub('', unicode(q))  # u'Canon  EOS  7D'
```

Can someone please explain to me why this is the case?

thanks,

Peter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because a standard (byte) string is not a Unicode string. Python does not know what encoding it's in (or if it's even Unicode at all!), and so has no way to determine whether a particular Unicode character matches some character in it. The solution is to tell Python it's Unicode, using the `unicode()` function, as you have figured out.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - so the take away message is "don't mix str and unicode strings (unless you're Dutch)"?

Comment: I think that, if you're Dutch, you just change the language so that all strings are Unicode by default.  :-)